# Enlightemnent, window content upside down

Tags: 13.10, desktop-environments, enlightenment

I've installed Enlightenment with this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vase/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install enlightenment
```

(Ubuntu 13.10 (Unity as default), amd64 with Enlightenment 0.18.0-alpha4)

But as I open my session with it, every window content is upside down:
[image: original image]

(And reversed & flipped with Gimp):

[image: flipped and reversed]

And to click on buttons, I have to click where they are normally:

[image: don't click on what you see!]

I did the installation on a bootable USB key too (with Ubuntu installed on it) but I have the same result.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just waited and, after an update via the update manager, everything went right!

It updated to 0.18.2!